# Extracting rows from list in data frame where at max numbers

Tags: python, pandas

So i've been given a pandas data frame and created a definition for the maximum variable in one column.

max_energy = D202['USAGE'].max()
max_energy

I need to extract the rows with maximum values

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 df = D202[D202['USAGE'].eq(D202['USAGE'].max())]
```